# Best 'subdomain' in maven repository url

Tags: url, maven, repository, naming-conventions

I've got some code that I want to contribute back to 'the world', open source world.

I'd like to put it up on 'central repository' at sonatype.com.

My question is, what's a good repository name based on my code base in the company, and that which I will remote/contribute to open source at sonatype?

Examples:

```
(would be in company's private repository)
com.mycompanyname
com.mycompanyname.variousnamesandprojects.blah.blah


(would be in company's private repository)
com.mycompanyname.commons
~or~
com.mycompanyname.oss.contributions
~or~
com.mycompanyname.youridea
~or~
com.mycomapnyname.convention
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a groupId which is similar to your companies domain in reverse order as in java packages as well. As you suggested the things like

```
com.mycompanyname.WHATEVER
```

The *WHATEVER* should you group like you need to. What i not recommend is to have different groupId's inside the company and outside. 
Within that groupId com.mycompanyname you can make grouping like you need for example:

```
com.mycompanyname.common
com.mycompanyname.maven
com.mycompanyname.maven.plugins
com.mycompanyname.projectName
```